# Trying to use 2 models in the one cshtml(MVC 4) but getting a dictionary error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Basically I had to create a ParentView for my classes in a class file as I was trying to use both classes in the one cshtml file.

```
@model JavaTutorial.Models.ParentView
@{
    ViewBag.Quiz = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<h2>Quiz: @Model.Quiz.Title</h2>

@if (Model.Quiz.Title == "IF Statements")
{

    <h2>Quiz 24</h2>
using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Evaluation.Questions)
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

The problem is when I run it I get the following now:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'JavaTutorial.Models.Quiz', but this dictionary requires a model item
>   of type 'JavaTutorial.Models.ParentView'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item
>   passed into the dictionary is of type 'JavaTutorial.Models.Quiz', but
>   this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'JavaTutorial.Models.ParentView'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I want it that when the link 'IF statements' is clicked my Evaluation method is called. Maybe there is an easier way of doing this?

**Controller:**

```
            public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var quiz = storeDB.Quizzes.Find(id);
            return View(quiz);
        }


        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            var evalVM = new Evaluation();

            //the below is hardcoded for DEMO. you may get the data from some  
            //other place and set the questions and answers

            var q1 = new Question { ID = 1, QuestionText = "What is your favourite language" };
            q1.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 12, AnswerText = "PHP" });
            q1.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 13, AnswerText = "ASP.NET" });
            q1.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 14, AnswerText = "Java" });
            evalVM.Questions.Add(q1);

            var q2 = new Question { ID = 2, QuestionText = "What is your favourite DB" };
            q2.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 16, AnswerText = "SQL Server" });
            q2.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 17, AnswerText = "MySQL" });
            q2.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 18, AnswerText = "Oracle" });
            evalVM.Questions.Add(q2);

            return View(evalVM);           
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Test(Evaluation model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var q in model.Questions)
                {
                    var qId = q.ID;
                    var selectedAnswer = q.SelectedAnswer;
                    // Save the data 

                }
                return RedirectToAction("ThankYou"); //PRG Pattern
            }
            //reload questions
            return View(model);
        }
```

**Class Quiz.cs**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace JavaTutorial.Models
{
    public class Quiz
    {
        [Key]
        public int QuizId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int difficulty { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    }

    public class Question
    {
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string QuestionText { set; get; }
        public List<Answer> Answers { set; get; }
        [Required]
        public string SelectedAnswer { set; get; }
        public Question()
        {
            Answers = new List<Answer>();
        }
    }
    public class Answer
    {
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string AnswerText { set; get; }
    }
    public class Evaluation
    {
        public List<Question> Questions { set; get; }
        public Evaluation()
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>();
        }
    }

    public class ParentView
    {
        public Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
        public Question Question { get; set; }
        public Answer Answer { get; set; }
        public Evaluation Evaluation{ get; set; }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can we see your controller action code?

Comment: @Oliver added in there. just on the controller the details handles the quiz class and then the Test works with the evaluation/question/answer class.

Comment: @user3055450 use a View Model to combine the 2 models into one. Then call that view model in the view

Answer (score 2):

in your first line

```
@model JavaTutorial.Models.ParentView
```

you are declaring your model a `ParentView`.  If you want to have both those classes in your model, you need to create a third class that contains both of them.  A `Tuple<ParentView, Quiz>` will work, or just your own implementation:

```
public class ParentAndQuiz
{
    public ParentView  parentView {get; set;
    public Quiz quiz { get; set; }
}
```